# How permission groups (by default) in hdfs work?? Why all users files belong to supergroup?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera-cdh

I am absolutely confused about how permission groups in hdfs work, at least in my cluster. Let's say i have unix user kranach, that belongs to group bla. I have hadoop2 cluster setup from CDH5, there is unix group *hadoop* to which users hdfs, yarn and mapred belogns (but not kranach, he has nothing to do with hadoop).

Now, my root directory in hdfs has permissions like following

`drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs supergroup          0 2015-01-27 23:08 /`

So, I am assuming that since me, kranach, does not belong to supergroup, i should not be allowed to create directories under /. However when i do this:

`kranach@czarnobog:~$ hdfs dfs -mkdir /bla
kranach@czarnobog:~$ hdfs dfs -ls  /
Found 6 items
drwxr-xr-x   - kranach supergroup          0 2015-01-27 23:27 /bla`

So I've just created directory, that belongs to me and group supergroup. But i am not in supergroup, and shouldn't be allowed to create dirs there in a first place! According to hadoop documentation (http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_permissions_guide.html#Configuration+Parameters) by default hadoop just checks linux user "group" command, which clearly for mine user doesn't show supergroup (it doesn't even exist).

Could anyone please explain me this behaviour? And tell how to prevent it (i.e. I want to have on this box users, that are allowed to access hdfs, but can't write there anything).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, long story short, looks like security was disabled after all. I just didn't know that server-side services do not use /etc/hadoop/conf, but each has their own configs inside `/var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/_process-name/`. These can also be seen in CM UI e.g. CM ->HDFS -> Instances -> NameNode -> Processes -> hdfs-site.xml.

http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Storage-Random-Access-HDFS/HDFS-default-permissioning-workes-weird-CDH5-1/m-p/24137#U24137